# Cannot Create Extra Operator Link on DatabricksRunNowOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow, databricks

I'm currently trying to build an extra link on the DatabricksRunNowOperator in airflow so I can quickly access the databricks run without having to rummage through the logs. As a starting point I'm simply trying to add a link to google in the task instance menu. I've followed the procedure shown in [this tutorial](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/define_extra_link.html) creating the following code placed within my airflow home plugins folder:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperatorLink
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksRunNowOperator

class DBLogLink(BaseOperatorLink):
    name = 'run_link'

    operators = [DatabricksRunNowOperator]

    def get_link(self, operator, dttm):
        return "https://www.google.com"

class AirflowExtraLinkPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "extra_link_plugin"
    operator_extra_links = [DBLogLink(), ]
```

However the extra link does not show up, even after restarting the webserver etc:

[image: airflow ui image]

Here's the code I'm using to create the DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksRunNowOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DATABRICKS_CONN_ID = '____'

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 2, 13),
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'testing_notebook', 
    default_args = args, 
    schedule_interval = timedelta(days=1)
)

DatabricksRunNowOperator(
    task_id = 'mail_reader',
    dag = dag,
    databricks_conn_id = DATABRICKS_CONN_ID,
    polling_period_seconds=1,
    job_id = ____,
    notebook_params = {____}
)
```

I feel like I'm missing something really basic, but I just can't figure it out.

#### Additional info

- Airflow version 1.10.9
- Running on ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked it out. You need to have your webserver running as [RBAC](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/add-new-role.html). This means setting up airflow with authentication and adding users. RBAC can be turned on by setting `rbac = True` in your *airflow.cfg* file.